# Which more topic should be covered in my undergraduate program?

Tags: finance

Below is the topics covered in my undergraduate economics program. I want to know which course should I take to get a full overview of topics in finance today.

- Econometrics
- Micro, Macro Economics
- Insurance
- Investment (first half luenberger textbook)
- Asset pricing (discrete time, CAPM, continuous time with black scholes model, pricing kernel and risk neutral method, stochastic calculus)

Comment: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/229/question-about-career-advice

Comment: I believe we should keep the forum free of career and education questions before it gets "polluted" with tons of questions à la "should I take econometrics II or Linear Algebra II"? See also here: http://meta.quant.stackexchange.com/questions/13/idea-about-education-questions?rq=1

Comment: @selfTaught: Then will you join me in voting to close? It's only on this site that you (and I) can do this with < 500 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Asset pricing, but it depends on what kind of finance you're talking about.